# Windows error 0xc0000428 error from boot

Tags: windows, boot, system-recovery

I am not 100% sure what OS is at this time but I believe Windows 10 Home OS on the laptop. I get this error in a bluescreen right from boot with no other information other than the code.

After running some of the recovery tools it suggests me to run a chkdsk command. I can't get to that due to not having the media. Is there anyway around this to fix the boot issue or does it need to be reloaded?

Note: I am about to do a hardrive test. Could the hardive be bad?

My error is \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi is corrupt and unreadable

Comment: You can try booting in safe mode (F8). Or boot from a USB stick with Windows installation media that you can obtain directly from Microsoft.

Comment: My error is \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi is corrupt and unreadable. Please run the Chkdsk Utility

Comment: Errors in the EFI file prevent booting in any mode and that information should be in the question itself, not in comments. Please [edit]. And, again, *boot from a USB stick with Windows installation media that you can obtain directly from Microsoft* and try a repair from there. But it is very likely your HDD or SSD is now defective. Logical errors, the errors that can be corrected by the suggested command, usually DON'T happen in the EFI partition because it's accessed only when booting.

Comment: Refer to the following link to see if it helps, since the error message could be different, but it also should fix the boot the issue.https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc0000428/